# When running query select count(*) from table in hive Map task is finishing but not reducer task finishing

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, cloudera, reducers

I am using cloudera 5.9 version. And i tried a simple select count(*) from table query from hive CLI. The job never returning results. As per the logs The Map task is getting finished 100% but reducer task is not even starting.

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2018-06-22 05:56:03,019 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-06-22 05:56:22,789 Stage-1 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 11.67 sec
2018-06-22 05:56:41,472 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
2018-06-22 05:57:41,547 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
2018-06-22 05:58:42,532 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
2018-06-22 05:59:43,423 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
2018-06-22 06:00:44,304 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
2018-06-22 06:01:45,161 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
2018-06-22 06:02:45,938 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
2018-06-22 06:03:46,749 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 31.45 sec
```

I tried running for hours but still there is no progress in reduce task. And i checked the logs. There is no information available in the logs.

Can someone please help me to understand what might have happened in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can the status of map reduce job by hitting Job tracker and Task tracker web UI or from command line using command: hadoop job -status <YOUR_JOB_ID>

Comment: @ReenaUpadhya, I checked it. The status is **RUNNING** but it is not moving even after 4 to 5 hours.

Comment: How many records in the table? May be you can check hadoop logs and if that also doesn't help, then kill the running job and run again the query.

Comment: it has some around 30k records (very small table). And i have sufficient resources available.

Comment: you tried by killing the job and executing again?